# Internal error occurred while creating dependency graph: ASSERTION FAILURE

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Why do I get this assertion failure? I am using Xcode 3.1.2.

```
Checking Dependencies
Internal error occurred while creating dependency graph: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DevToolsBase/DevToolsBase-1204/pbxcore/NativeBuildSystem/XCDependencyNode.m:396
Details:  command should be an instance inheriting from XCDependencyCommand, but it is nil
Object:   <XCDependencyNode:0x03379d50>
Method:   -addDependedNode:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x2c1e760>{name = (null), num = 4}
Backtrace:
  0  0x00725da2 -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DevToolsCore)
  1  0x0078a360 _XCAssertionFailureHandler (in DevToolsCore)
  2  0x005e1f66 -[XCDependencyNode addDependedNode:] (in DevToolsCore)
  3  0x005e5c4c -[XCResourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot copyResourceFile:ofType:toDirectory:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  4  0x005e55d6 -[XCResourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot computeDependenciesForBuildFileReference:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  5  0x005e34b4 -[XCBuildPhaseDGSnapshot computeDependenciesForAllBuildFileReferencesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  6  0x005e2b13 -[XCBuildPhaseDGSnapshot computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7  0x005e4ebb -[XCResourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  8  0x005d8ebe -[XCProductTypeSpecification computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  9  0x005d4866 -[XCNativeTargetDGSnapshot computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 10  0x005d1efd -[PBXTargetBuildContext createDependencyGraphWithTargetDGSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
 11  0x005d10c5 -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) dg_setTargetSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
 12  0x936199dd __invoking___ (in CoreFoundation)
 13  0x936193c8 -[NSInvocation invoke] (in CoreFoundation)
 14  0x005d0aeb -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) processDependencyGraphEvents] (in DevToolsCore)
 15  0x936199dd __invoking___ (in CoreFoundation)
 16  0x936193c8 -[NSInvocation invoke] (in CoreFoundation)
 17  0x005d0458 -[XCInvocationQueue _processNextInvocationInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
 18  0x005d0107 -[XCInvocationQueue _processInvocationsInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
 19  0x91a11e0d -[NSThread main] (in Foundation)
 20  0x91a119b4 __NSThread__main__ (in Foundation)
 21  0x9757d155 _pthread_start (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 22  0x9757d012 thread_start (in libSystem.B.dylib)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem too and found that my issue related to the following configuration settings:

```
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = $(BUILD_DIR)/release/bin
CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR  = build/$(CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)
```

I removed the settings, just as a test, and the error that Xcode was producing went away.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like XCode is crashing trying to build your application.

Judging by the method names in the traceback, it's looking at dependencies trying to figure out what to build. You might be able to work around the problem by doing a "clean all targets" and trying again.

You might also want to file a bug report at http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/

Comment: i am not able to clean target nor able to build the app